# What does the error mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, admob

```
Ld /Users/michaelsonsamuels/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-hedtrampxpseetfcmcksycqvmpuk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Video.app/Video normal i386
    cd "/Users/michaelsonsamuels/Desktop/Xcode /Video"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/michaelsonsamuels/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-hedtrampxpseetfcmcksycqvmpuk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/michaelsonsamuels/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-hedtrampxpseetfcmcksycqvmpuk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/michaelsonsamuels/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-hedtrampxpseetfcmcksycqvmpuk/Build/Intermediates/Video.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Video.build/Objects-normal/i386/Video.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework StoreKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework MessageUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o /Users/michaelsonsamuels/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-hedtrampxpseetfcmcksycqvmpuk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Video.app/Video

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_kGADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ld /Users/michaelsonsamuels/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-hedtrampxpseetfcmcksycqvmpuk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Video.app/Video normal i386
    cd "/Users/michaelsonsamuels/Desktop/Xcode /Video"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/michaelsonsamuels/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-hedtrampxpseetfcmcksycqvmpuk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/michaelsonsamuels/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-hedtrampxpseetfcmcksycqvmpuk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/michaelsonsamuels/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-hedtrampxpseetfcmcksycqvmpuk/Build/Intermediates/Video.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Video.build/Objects-normal/i386/Video.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework StoreKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework MessageUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o /Users/michaelsonsamuels/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-hedtrampxpseetfcmcksycqvmpuk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Video.app/Video

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_kGADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o


  "_kGADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:


      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks.

Comment: what u r tried to do? if u didn't provide it in the question, how can we find a solution?

Comment: Have u added the framework for the latest Google Admob ?? Please google it :)....

Comment: Yes i downloaded the latest framework from Admob... BTW i'm just tryin to display a banner at the bottom end of a single view display app with no code in it....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your classes are missing from Build target. I don't know about your project structure and files but it looks like GADBannerView and GADRequest classes are missing.

Remove these files from your project. add them again and remember to check "ADD TO TARGET" checkbox.

Comment: Hey thanx tried it but dint work. It is added to target, There is a copy of the Admob SDK in my project.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `libGoogleAdMobAds.a` to the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.

Answer (score 1):

this error shows that u haven't added GADBannerView, and GADRequest classes.

please check by following this steps:

in XCode select your Project in the Target Section then switch to BuildPhases->CompileSources

here check for GADBannerView.m and GADRequest.m files.

XCode->Your Project in Target section->BuildPhases->CompileSources

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Gadbannervew and its classes have all been added :) i dint add adframework which did the trick thanks anyway :)